# How to use regex in vim to search for two consecutive words?

Tags: regex, vim

I know that it's possible to search for two different words on the same line by doing the following:
`.*blue\&.*red`

but when I try to search for two words (with whitespace in between) it says nothing is found.

`.*blue green \&.*red`

How do I quantify the regex that searches for the string `'blue green'` in vim?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can search for 2 consecutive words like this:

```
blue\W\+red
```

i.e. `first word` followed by 1 or more non-word characters followed by `second word`